# How to explore ASP.NET MVC internal functions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm PHP developer but trying to learn ASP.NET MVC. In PHP when i need to look at method implementation i just go to it's definition and just reading it, because it's written in plain PHP.

In ASP.NET MVC i'm writing a View and want to see how @Html.ActionLink works, but i cannot. Maximum i get is function header not it's actual code.

Help needed, please.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you want to see the source. Have you checked the MSDN documentation?

Comment: @jrummell because i learned PHP by reading web frameworks source code and find this extremely useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is Open Source**. You can check the source code and see what each method is doing. Source code is available at codeplex.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

ASP.NET MVC,Web API and Razor is Open Source. The best thing is that, You can even contribute to that. More details in Scott's [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVC4ASPNETWebAPIAndASPNETWebPagesV2RazorNowAllOpenSourceWithContributions.aspx) here

If you want to look into the source code of any other stuff where source code is not available like the above, you can use any Decompiling tools. I use [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and it is great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Reflector`](http://www.reflector.net/) to see the implementations of .net functions.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC is an Open Source Framework.

You can get the code [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC sources are available at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Even in php if you want to show the source code of an builtin function like `md5` you must download the source code.

Now In Asp.net mvc you can download the source code 
check this link.
https://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781